# Cannot run Django with active venv in zsh

Tags: python, django, zsh, python-venv

I've got a properly activated venv in zsh, because I can see `(venv)` at the beginning of the prompt, but when I try to run Django with the command `python manage.py runserver` I've the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 17, in <module>
    "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

If I run which `which python` I can see `python: aliased to /usr/local/bin/python3.7` that it seems wrong, because I expect something like `/Users/myuser/Python-Projects/test/venv/bin/python`. In fact if I disable the venv the result of `which python` is the same.

I tried to the same steps with bash and everything works fine, so I guess I've got something wrong with zsh, but I don't know what.

As a workaround to run Django I must run the command `venv/bin/python manage.py runserver`, so it's like the root `python` in some way is broken. I tried to update zsh to latest version, but problem is still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're on the right track by checking `which python`. You're not using the python from your virtual environment if the path is /usr/local/bin, which means you're either not setting it up correctly or not starting it correctly. 

I always start the environment with:

`python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment`

Then `source /path/bin/activate`

Then double check pip and python using the `which` command and `--version`.

Answer (score 2):

Problem found. It was an alias for `python` in `.zshrc`.